# Why can't you re-upvote comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

Pretty straightforward question:

- Why can't we re-upvote comments?

For example, when I accidentally upvote a comment, almost instantly cancel my upvote because it was a mistake and realise after reading the comment that it deserves being upvoted, I can't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is intentional, see [Cancelling upvote on comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/cancelling-upvote-on-comment).

PS: Most of your recent "how does this site work" or "why does this site work as it does" questions have been discussed and answered on Meta.SE, some of them years ago. Please use the search functionality there for these kind of questions.